# What does "humans do" in this sentence refers to?

Tags: syntax

I have a question.

> It's wrong for scientists to presume the environment other species
> sense in the same way **humans do**.

What does "humans do" refer to? Is it "humans sense" or "humans presume"?
I think it refers to "humans sense". Does this sentence convey similar meaning as "It's wrong for scientists to presume other species sense the environment in the same way humans do"?

Comment: That sentence is nonsense, so I can't be sure what "do" refers to. My best guess is "sense", but I can't be confident.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Shouldn't it be _other species sense the environment_?

Comment: Oh, thank you for your responses. I guess the sentence is grammatically wrong and doesn't make sense. I just happened to come across the sentence somewhere. How about using "presume" instead of "assume"? In that case, it isn't grammatically correct, either?

Comment: Typically one presumes a fact. So “the environment” doesn’t work as the object of *presume*. Maybe the original source that you found meant “the environment **is**”? But in that case, the end of the sentence is meaningless.

Comment: The choice of verb makes no difference at all. It's the order of the words that is peculiar. I think you may be misquoting the sentence. Your version must be the intended meaning.

Comment: Please [cite the source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). And if you have another question, you should ask another question. (Don't ask new questions in comments.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is grammatically incorrect.

I would presume it should be written this way:

> It is wrong for scientists to presume other species sense the environment in the same way humans do.

The presumption is about the way other species sense the environment - that they sense the same way humans do (sense).